# Status table join for multiple states

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables, A and B, A contains a list of entries and B for each of those entries multiple status rows (0-n, grouped by date with a status 0 for okay and 1 for failure).

Now I would like to select all rows from A with their respective most recent status and its date as well as the most recent failure and its date (failure defined as having at least one entry with 1).

I tried something with two left joins but am not convinced it is the optimal solution and also still have issues with determining the correct number of failures (SUM(b2.status))

```
SELECT a.id, b1.date, SUM(b1.status), b2.date, SUM(b2.status) FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b1 ON b1.aid=a.id
LEFT JOIN tableb b2 ON b2.aid=a.id

WHERE (b1.date=(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM tableb WHERE aid=a.id) OR b1.date IS NULL)
AND (b2.date=(SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM tableb WHERE aid=a.id GROUP BY `date` HAVING SUM(`status`)>0) OR b2.date IS NULL)

GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, I think every assumption I made to this point has been wrong.  I think this will give you what you want.  It will give you the total number of failures for the latest date that had a failure.

I'm not sure how performance will be on a very large database, but it works fine on a smaller one.

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(b1.date) status_date, SUM(b1.status) latest_status, 
       b2.date latest_failure,
       b2.total_failures

FROM tablea a

     LEFT JOIN tableb b1
     ON b1.aid = a.id
     AND b1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id)

     LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT aid, date, count(*) total_failures FROM tableb WHERE status > 0 GROUP BY aid, date) b2
     ON b2.aid = a.id
     AND b2.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0)

GROUP BY a.id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That seems to do the trick. My second join was apparently incomplete.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that if b1 was returning 2 rows and b2 was returning 2 rows, you would get 4 rows and your failure count would be doubled.  Or if you have 3 rows, it could be tripled, etc.  With the above, b2 only returns a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT a.id, b1.date status_date, b1.status, b2.date latest_failure, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0) total_failures

FROM tablea a

     LEFT JOIN tableb b1
     ON b1.aid = a.id
     AND b1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id)

     LEFT JOIN tableb b2
     ON b2.aid = a.id
     AND b2.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0)
```

This is assuming that the tableb.date field is a datetime and is unique.  Otherwise you may wish to use an id field instead.

Comment: Thanks, tried both but not getting the right result with either unfortunately. Yes, date is not unique as it groups the status entries.

Comment: Yeah if date is not unique, this won't work.  I was thinking date might be a datetime field.  Do you have a unique id on tableb?  If so would the max(ID) be the latest one?

Comment: If possible I would like to avoid introducing an id. Also I guess it would only take the last entry, while it should take the last batch of entries (by date). Basically the logic would be, fetch all from A and then join B and give me the date and combined status of the most recent entries along with the date and combined status where the latter is >0 (failure).

Comment: Ok, I got you.  I was thinking you wanted the status of the latest record in tableb, not the status of the latest date.  Now I understand what you are doing better.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this also.  Not sure which one is more efficient.  You could try it both ways.

```
SELECT a.id, b1.date status_date, b1.status, 
       (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0) latest_failure, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0) total_failures

FROM tablea a

     LEFT JOIN tableb b1
     ON b1.aid = a.id
     AND b1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(b1.date) status_date, SUM(b1.status) latest_status, 
       (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0) latest_failure,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableb  WHERE aid = a.id AND status > 0) total_failures

FROM tablea a

     LEFT JOIN tableb b1
     ON b1.aid = a.id
     AND b1.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableb WHERE aid = a.id)

GROUP BY a.id;
```

If you could have multiple failures for a day, and want to show the status as "1", then change this:

SUM(b1.status) latest_status

to:

MAX(b1.status) latest_status.

Comment: Thanks again, however that would still count the total overall failures and not only for the specific last failure. I guess I didnt explain it well enough. Each entry in A has a number of entries in B which are _grouped_ by date. Each group is an individual data set. And here I now want to determine the most recent group overall (regardless of the status) and the most recent group with a SUM(status) larger than 0.